# Specifying Typescript return type that implements interface with additional fields

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a function that returns an object which extends the FooInterface class. I want to restrict the return type to classes that implement FooInterface but also have an additional field.

```
interface FooInterface {
   readonly banana: string
}

function doThing() : FooInterface {

    return { 
        banana: 'blah',
        additionalField: 'blah2', // Must have
    }
}
```

How can I define the return type of `doThing()` to specify that `additionalField` be included? If there a way to do this just using the function definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```js
function doThing() : FooInterface & { additionalField: string } {
    return { 
        banana: 'blah',
        additionalField: 'blah2', // Must have
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't realize you could specify multiple interfaces like that. Very convenient.